# How do I locally reconfigure a subproject

Tags: mks-integrity

I have a variant sandbox, with several subprojects in it configured to also follow a variant, but there is one which is configured to be fixed on a build. *(Namely, the sources are variants, while the make toolchain is developed by another team, and we want to use a specific version of it.)*

What I need to do, is change the build version of this subproject, but only for my local sandbox, without updating the member revisions for the rest of the team to resynchronise.

I read things about doing a checkout at specific checkpoint, which could be fine, expect that they suggest getting the revision at a specific time, which doesn't ensure at all that it was actually this version that was used in the checkpoint. As a temporary workaround, I created a build sandbox of the checkpoint I'm interested in and merged both sandboxes locally on the hard drive, which I find very lame... Is there a better solution?

Comment: Why do you find a build sandbox merged with your local sandbox to be lame?  Obviously you have a reason, but knowing what that is would help clear some things up.

Comment: When doing this, I lose track of what is really in my sandbox. For example, some minutes ago, I had a subproject configured as 1.54.1.202 and needed to make some tests with 1.54.1.206. So I created a sandbox for the later and merged it using Beyond Compare. But in MKS, the subproject is still shown as 1.54.1.202 with a lot of locally changed files. If I need to work on it again in 2 weeks, who knows if I will remember that? Furthermore, the manipulation is rather complex for something that is often easier on other CM tools.